# disable button submission when selected option is disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using jquery and i want to disable my button initially to prevent it from submitting null values.

here is my code

```
<form method = "get" action = "" >
        <div id="select-vehicle">
         <select class = "form-control">
            <option  selected disabled  > Select Vehicles</option>

        </select>

        </div>
        <button type = "submit" value = "submit" id= "submit">TEST</button>
        </form>
```

and here is my jquery right now

```
var workers = ["car1", "car2", "car3"];
        for(var i=0; i< workers.length;i++)
    {
    //creates option tag
      jQuery('<option/>', {
            value: workers[i],
            html: workers[i]
            }).appendTo('#select-vehicle select'); //appends to select if parent div has id dropdown
    }
  $('button').click(function(event) {
    var value = $( "select" ).val();
    $('form').attr('action', 'accessories/vehicles/' + value +'/');
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can disable by default your submit button using disable property after on change of select option, remove the disable property of the button if its value is not blank

Comment: got it thanks!!, guess i'm too caught on complicated answers!.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jQuery code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var workers = ["car1", "car2", "car3"];
        for(var i=0; i< workers.length;i++)
    {
    //creates option tag
      jQuery('<option/>', {
            value: workers[i],
            html: workers[i]
            }).appendTo('#select-vehicle select'); //appends to select if parent div has id dropdown
    }
    
    jQuery('#select-vehicle select').on('change', function(){
     if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){
         jQuery('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
        }else{
         jQuery('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
    
    if( !jQuery('#select-vehicle select').val() ){
     jQuery('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
    }else{
     jQuery('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  $('button').click(function(event) {
    var value = $( "select" ).val();
    $('form').attr('action', 'accessories/vehicles/' + value +'/');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method = "get" action = "" >
        <div id="select-vehicle">
         <select class = "form-control">
            <option  selected disabled  > Select Vehicles</option>

        </select>

        </div>
        <button type = "submit" value = "submit" id= "submit">TEST</button>
        </form>
```

It also disable the submit button if any of the option has no value.

Comment: Glad to know, I can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can initially disable your button by adding the `disabled` attribute to your button:

```
<button type = "submit" value = "submit" id= "submit" disabled>TEST</button>
```

Then when you change the option in the drop-down you can remove the `disabled` attribute to enable the button:

```
$(".form-control").change(function() {
    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fjp3L4yb/1/

Answer (score 0):

to answer my question

```
<button type = "submit" value = "submit" id= "submit" disabled>TEST</button> $('select').change(function(){
      if ($(this).val())
      {
        $("button").removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

- Disabling the button on page load
- enabling button using onchange
- Checking input before submitting the form

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#select-vehicle select').change(function(){
          if ($(this).val()){
              $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
          }
      });

      $("form").submit(function(event){
          if (!$('#select-vehicle select').val()) {
              $("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: That does not disable the button, a user could click the button until his mouse broke and wonder why noting is happening.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, had some connection trouble:

Initially the button is disabled:

```
<button disabled type = "submit" value = ...
```

And assuming the select has the selected index of 0 when page loads

```js
var workers = ["car1", "car2", "car3"];
$('#select-vehicle select')
  .append(
    workers.map(
      worker =>
        jQuery(
          '<option/>'
          ,{
            value: worker,
            html: worker
          }
        )
    )
  )
  .on(
    "change"
    ,e => 
      e.target.selectedIndex===0
      ?$("button").attr("disabled","true")
      :$("button").removeAttr("disabled")
  )
;
$('button').click(function(event) {
  var value = $( '#select-vehicle select' ).val();
  $('form').attr('action', 'accessories/vehicles/' + value +'/');
  //remove this or the form will not be submitted
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($("form").attr("action"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method = "get" action = "" >
      <div id="select-vehicle">
        <select class = "form-control">
          <option  selected disabled  > Select Vehicles</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button disabled type = "submit" value = "submit" id= "submit">TEST</button>
    </form>
```